# Record request from Postman through vpn (Proxy / Interceptor)

Tags: api, proxy, request, postman, interceptor

I have used Postman in the past and I was able to record my request using the interceptor and proxy features, but currently, I'm using a VPN and I'm not able to record the request, is there something else we need to setup in order to capture them when a VPN is in the middle?